CSS move div at the same line
I have this layout, and want to move the second column on the same line. So both divs with 1 be on the same line. Is it possible to do this using something other than transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 102px)); Any other way to make the div fill to up?



.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px
}

.rev {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box red">1</div>
    <div class="box blue">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col rev">
    <div class="box red">1</div>
    <div class="box blue">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
    <div>X</div>
  </div>
</div>



Here is a link https://jsfiddle.net/nhpeurz5/

Try addinng align-items: end; to .row class. And also remove css transform: translateY(-100%); from class .rev.

Make the height of the row equal to 100px and you will get what you want


.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px
}

.rev {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box red">1</div>
    <div class="box blue">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col rev">
    <div class="box red">1</div>
    <div class="box blue">2</div>
    <div class="box green">3</div>
    <div>X</div>
  </div>
</div>



